# What is the most efficient way to get the UTF-16LE bytes for a Delphi UnicodeString?

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-16

As Delphi uses UTF-16 for its internal representation, is it correct to simply copy all bytes of a UnicodeString over to a byte array?

Is this platform-independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to play the safe card: `TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes('Hello World')`. The current implementation looks quite efficient and you don't have to worry about future platforms.